# CS CART -Wrong css path

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, cs-cart

I am new in cs cart.
I have done the following steps

```
1.downloaded a cs-cart-V3 website to my localhost.
2.Change database setting,and import database.
3.$config['http_host'] = 'localhost'; added in **config.local.php** file.
4.Removed .htaccess file from root folder.
```

**My problem is**

The site was loaded,But the path of css is wrong.It is trying to load from  **localhost** Not from **localhost/subfolder**,

Where i need to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check config.local.php

Mainly the following lines:

```
// Host and directory where software is installed on no-secure server
$config['http_host'] = '';
$config['http_path'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the store-front URL is also correct. It can be checked:

1. In the cscart_companies table in the database (storefront and secure_storefront columns)
2. On the Administration -> Stores page (Storefront URL and Secure storefront URL fields)

At the end, do not forget to clear cache. You can do it by adding the "?cc&ctpl" to the URL in the admin panel. E.g.

http://your_domain.com/your_admin.php?cc&ctpl